# How to Add has_many association field to array of models in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add has_many models LoanAmtPerSvcType to LoanContract array.
Below is my code, but it does not work.
When i check **@contracts[0].loan_amt_per_svc_type.count** , it return '0'

```
@members.each do |c|
        @contracts << LoanContract.new(
            :customer_id => c.id,
            :season_id => @season.id,
            :loan_type_id => @loan_type.id,
            :cus_group_id => @group.id,
            contract_date: @contract_date,
            loan_duration: @loan_duration,
            inspector_id: @inspector.id,
            mgr_id: @manager.id,
            user_id: @user.id)
      end
     @contracts.each do |lc|
        lc.loan_amt_per_svc_type = [LoanAmtPerSvcType.new(customer_service_type_id: 1), LoanAmtPerSvcType.new(customer_service_type_id: 2)]
     end
render :text => @contracts[0].loan_amt_per_svc_type.count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@contracts[0].loan_amt_per_svc_type.count` return 0, because you didn't save your contracts into the database.
You can use `LoanContract.create` instead of `LoanContract.new`. Also with associations.
If you only want to know count of `loan_amt_per_svc_type` use `size` method.

```
@contracts[0].loan_amt_per_svc_type.size
```